# Wait until geoJSON ajax call completed

Tags: leaflet, geojson, ajax

I use the codes below to make an ajax call requesting points and show it on the map:

```
var layer_kos = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("<?php echo base_url('assets/GIS/layer/request_kos.php');?>",{
pointToLayer: function (feature,latlng) {
    addRowTable(feature,latlng);
    tablesaw(feature);

    buffer(feature,latlng);//this function is used to add points to my own array
    return L.marker (latlng, {
        icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
            icon:'bed',
            markerColor: 'cadetblue' ,
            prefix:'fa'
        }),
        title: feature.properties.nama,
        riseOnHover: true
    });
}, 
filter:filterkos,
onEachFeature:function(feature, layer){
        layer.bindPopup(
            "<h6><center>" + feature.properties.nama + "<center></h6>"+
            "<table> <tr> <td> <h6> HARGA  </h6> </td> <td> Rp. " +  feature.properties.harga + ",00" + 
            "</td></tr> <tr> <td> <h6> FASILITAS </h6> </td> <td> " + feature.properties.fasilitas + "</td> </tr> </table>"
            // "<left> HARGA : Rp" + feature.properties.harga + ",00<left> <br>"+ 
            // "<left> FASILITAS : " + feature.properties.fasilitas + "<left>"
            )   
}
}).addTo(map);
```

I need to works with the array obtained by buffer(feature, latlng), only when the ajax completed. I've tried on dataLoadComplete bellow but it doesn't seem to work.

```
layer_kos.on('dataLoadComplete',function(e){
        alert(buffers.length);
});
```

What is the callback function that I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is the fallback function for data loading:

```
layer_kos.on('data:loaded', function() { })
```

More can be found in the [doc](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax)